# Dynamic create li when you click add button angular 7

Tags: html, angular, angular7

I am new to angular, wanted to add address every time click the button "Add Address". I wanted it to be dynamic then I will submit.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Address: </label>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="addAddress()" >Add Address</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let add of contact.address | async">
            <label for="name">Type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="atype" required [(ngModel)]="add.type" name="atype">
            ....
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
addAddress() {
    let add = {
      id: 0,
      type: '',
      number: 0,
      street: '',
      unit: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zipcode: ''
    };
    this.contact.Address.push(add);
  }
```

when I click it does nothing but when I submit

I got empty arrays created:

```
Address: [{id: 0, type: "", number: 0, street: "", unit: "", city: "", state: "", zipcode: ""},…]
0: {id: 0, type: "", number: 0, street: "", unit: "", city: "", state: "", zipcode: ""}
1: {id: 0, type: "", number: 0, street: "", unit: "", city: "", state: "", zipcode: ""}
2: {id: 0, type: "", number: 0, street: "", unit: "", city: "", state: "", zipcode: ""}
```

Comment: please provide your full code to understand fully, and explain what you plan to achieve very clearly

Comment: I cant provide the whole code because it is too long. what do you need? I just get the segment where the address is processed. is this lacking?

Comment: what your code is doing now when you click addAddress, it pushes the add object to your array, with the values you initialized in your typescript. and when you submit, get that array back? if that is the processs, then your code is working well

Comment: yes it is supposed to be creating the all the fields as a input element, but it did not create it. nothing happens. there should be a newly create li element which have all the input for the object address now it just do nothing.

Comment: did you subscribe contactaddress to an observable. and from your typescript code i can see "this.contact.Address.push(add)" and in your html "let add of contact.address | async", pls use this same case for the "a" in your address for your html and typescript

Comment: thanks for mentioning this. will look this is up. maybe this is the problem. thanks. brb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo on the lower case and upper case:

Use the upper case **Address** in TS code, and the lower case on template:

```
this.contact.Address
```

There is also another issue, using `id` attribute in a repeat, you will get repeat ids in the template.

We should avoid using id in the template unless we have to, if we have to use the id in template, we should make the id unique.

Fixed on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-example-pvdhhh?file=src/app/app.component.html